# remove an item from a linked list c++

Tags: c++

I have a problem with the item removal function

```
void removeKey(int key) {
     ListElement *element = getElement(key);
         if (element != nullptr) {
             ListElement *nextElement = element->getNext();
             ListElement *previousElement = getPreviousElemnt(element);
             if (previousElement == nullptr) {//pierwszy element
                 firstElement = nextElement;
             } else if (nextElement == nullptr) { //
                   previousElement->setNext(nullptr);
             } else {
                   previousElement->setNext(nextElement);
             }
             delete element;
             size--;
         }
     }
}

 ListElement *getPreviousElemnt(ListElement *element) {
        ListElement *element1 = firstElement;
        if (element1 != nullptr) {
            while (element1->getNext() == element) {
                return element1;
            }
        }
        return nullptr;
    }
```

Removing the first element works well. 
When I want to remove an element from the center or from the end the program removes all elements to the left of it...

Comment: What is the code of `getPreviousElemnt` ?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/erase - don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: `while (element1->getNext() == element) {` is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `getPreviousElemnt()` is not looping correctly.  It should look more like this instead:

```
ListElement *getPreviousElemnt(ListElement *element) {
    ListElement *element1 = firstElement;
    while (element1 != nullptr) {
        ListElement *nextElement = element1->getNext();
        if (nextElement == element) {
            return element1;
        }
        element1 = nextElement;
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

And your `removeKey()` does not need so many `if..elseif..else` blocks, it can be simplified to this:

```
void removeKey(int key) {
    ListElement *element = getElement(key);
    if (element != nullptr) {
        ListElement *nextElement = element->getNext();
        ListElement *previousElement = getPreviousElemnt(element);
        if (previousElement != nullptr) {
            previousElement->setNext(nextElement);
        }
        if (firstElement == element) {
            firstElement = nextElement;
        }
        delete element;
        size--;
    }
}
```

However, `removeKey()` can be *greatly* optimized further if you simply don't use `getElement()` at all so you avoid having to loop through the list twice:

```
void removeKey(int key) {
    ListElement *element = firstElement;
    ListElement *previousElement = nullptr;
    while (element != nullptr) {
        if (element->getKey() == key) {
            ListElement *nextElement = element->getNext();
            if (previousElement != nullptr) {
                previousElement->setNext(nextElement);
            }
            if (firstElement == element) {
                firstElement = nextElement;
            }
            delete element;
            size--;
            return;
        }
        previousElement = element;
        element = nextElement;
    }
}
```

Or alternatively, update `getElement()` to optionally return the previous element:

```
ListElement* getElement(int key, ListElement** previousElement = nullptr) {
    if (previousElement) {
        *previousElement = nullptr;
    }
    ListElement *element = firstElement;
    ListElement *previousElement1 = nullptr;
    while (element != nullptr) {
        if (element->getKey() == key) {
            if (previousElement) {
                *previousElement = previousElement1;
            }
            return element;
        }
        previousElement1 = element;
        element = element->getNext();
    }
    return nullptr;
}

void removeKey(int key) {
    ListElement* previousElement;
    ListElement *element = getElement(key, &previousElement);
    if (element != nullptr) {
        ListElement *nextElement = element->getNext();
        if (previousElement != nullptr) {
            previousElement->setNext(nextElement);
        }
        if (firstElement == element) {
            firstElement = nextElement;
        }
        delete element;
        size--;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to fix the `getPreviousElement` of your code. Right now what it does is checks if the first element is the previous to required element. If yes it returns correctly. If no, it exits the while loop and returns nullptr. You need to continue looping till you get the element. I'm not posting the solution because it should be a learning exercise for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
ListElement *getPreviousElemnt(ListElement *element) {
        ListElement *element1 = firstElement;
        if (element1 != nullptr) {
            while (element1->getNext() != element) {  //<----change this
                element1 = element1->getNext();
            }
             return element1; //<-----return previous
        }
        return nullptr;
    }
```